# SimpleDateFormat.parse returns invalid date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am sending a valid date ("1705") and getting different parsed date ("1701")

any help on what to fix?
the print in the middle shows the valid date.

```
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYMM");
            System.out.println(exYear+exMonth);
            Date ccDate = sdf.parse(exYear+exMonth);
```

Comment: So the answer here is: don't assume that a certain string has a certain meaning. Just check the documentation first.

Answer (score 7):

`y` for year has to be in small case

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMM");
```

Refer complete notation explanation in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)